# PayPal Classic API TransactionSearch method won't return item/product sold

Tags: java, paypal

I am using the TransactionSearch() method to return a list of transactions and details about those transactions. It works just fine, except that I only have the Date, Amount, and other details about the transaction -- not including what the name of actual item that was sold.

I am using the following to make my API call:

```
                String transID = responseValues.get("L_TRANSACTIONID" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String timeStamp = responseValues.get("L_TIMESTAMP" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String timeZone = responseValues.get("L_TIMEZONE" + String.valueOf(counter));
                status = responseValues.get("L_STATUS" + String.valueOf(counter));
                type = responseValues.get("L_TYPE" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String amt = responseValues.get("L_AMT" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String fee = responseValues.get("L_FEEAMT" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String netAmt = responseValues.get("L_NETAMT" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String cCode = responseValues.get("L_CURRENCYCODE" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String name = responseValues.get("L_NAME" + String.valueOf(counter));
                String email = responseValues.get("L_EMAIL" + String.valueOf(counter));
```

As you can see there isn't any way of actually calling the name of the product that was sold. Does anyone know how I would be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) for any transaction you want those details for.  It will return all sorts of data about the transaction, including any cart item data that was included in the original payment request.

Comment: So meaning that after the list of transactions that were brought returned with transactionSearch(); I should then iterate through all those transaction IDs in order to return more info about those transactions?

Comment: If you need details for all of them, yes.